# NSF Career Grant Eligibility

Tags: funding, nsf

Is someone who is not a US citizen and doesn’t have a green card but is working as a faculty at a state university in the US eligible to apply for an NSF CAREER grant? I am not sure if citizenship/green card status of a person is crucial to apply for an NSF grant or the status of organization is more important. I have seen non-US citizens applying for USDA/NIFA grants through universities. I am not sure if this is same for an NSF grant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you meet the other requirements for eligibility, yes.

From [this FAQ](https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/2020/nsf20025/nsf20025.jsp):

> 10. I am not a U.S. Permanent Resident or U.S. Citizen or U.S. National. Can I apply to the CAREER Program?
>
> Yes. You may apply if you are employed at an eligible U.S. organization and meet the other CAREER eligibility requirements.